# Populate attribute from one element to another element in an each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do I populate the iframe src attribute with the href attribute from the `a` element? The iframe can be moved inside the `li.feed-item` element if needed.

I need this in something like an each function, since there are several `li` elements with different links.

Closest I got is this, but it fetches the first link to all iframes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('li.feed-item').each(function () {         
  var href = jQuery("li.feed-item a.colorbox.cboxElement").attr('href');
jQuery('li.feed-item a.colorbox.cboxElement iframe').attr('src', href);
});
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="feed-item">
        <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Tp-VAe59RyA"><img height="280" src="http://skateflix.se/wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/i1-ytimg-com/1384690600.jpg" width="280">
         <iframe allowfullscreen class="video-embed" height="100%" itemprop="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/werwerw4wer" width="100%">
         </iframe></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="feed-item">
        <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Tp-VAe59RyA"><img height="280" src="http://skateflix.se/wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/i1-ytimg-com/1384690600.jpg" width="280">
         <iframe allowfullscreen class="video-embed" height="100%" itemprop="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qq0u6vbzXXoeerer" width="100%">
         </iframe></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically refer always to `$(this)`, the currently iterated `li.feed-item`

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $('li.feed-item').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).find("a.cboxElement").attr('href');
     $(this).find("iframe").attr('src', href);
  });

});
```

Or even **simpler**, query first for your `iframe` and than lookup for the `a` parent:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $('li.feed-item iframe').attr("src", function() {
     return $(this).closest("a.cboxElement").attr('href');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'this' should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('li.feed-item').each(function () {  
      var href = jQuery(this).find("a.colorbox.cboxElement").attr('href');
    jQuery(this).attr('src', href);
    });
    });
```